# What is "heavy print" and where can I find a definition?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

From [here](http://articles.baltimoresun.com/1997-08-28/features/1997240163_1_fashion-leather-fur-trim)

> September Vogue weighs in with 734 pages of **heavy print**, Bazaar with 488.

What does "heavy print" mean?

Other examples:

> Old habits die hard. Respondents ages 65 and over were almost three times more likely than the average respondent to be **heavy print** newspaper readers.
>
> The use of different media has changed dramatically over time. It is a cliché that reading is in decline. But on the other hand we get considerable information from the Internet, which is a **heavy print** medium.

Google and Wikipedia searches return nothing concrete.

I found a similar question asked [here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/heavy-print.1781527/), but not really of use to finding the definition.

Comment: *Heavy print* means something completely different in each of your three examples.

Comment: "heavy TV watchers" would mean "people who watch a lot of TV".

Comment: **heavy print** is a term from advertising and graphic design that refers to a higher quality paper stock, generous use of ink, and possibly use of glossy page coatings, the overarching goal of which is to impress the reader with glitz.

Answer (score 2):

With the Vogue example, "734 pages of heavy print," I would initially understand it as "734 pages mainly consisting of text, without a lot of images." However, being familiar with the magazine itself, I think it more likely refers to the physical weight of the pages themselves -- it is, in fact, a physically heavy magazine. I'm especially inclined to think that since the sentence uses the phrase "weighs in," which could be metaphorical but seems like maybe it's not.

The second example really should be hyphenated for clarity, thus: "to be heavy print-newspaper readers." "Heavy" here is an adverb, amplifying the extent of "print-newspaper reading" that these people do.

In the last example about the internet, referring to it as a "heavy print medium," I think means that it is a medium with a high text-to-image ratio (I would dispute that on factual grounds, but that's what I understand it to be saying). A good editor would probably change it to calling the internet a "print-heavy medium," which has the same meaning I just described but is a much more common way to phrase it.

Answer (score 1):

With 'Respondents ages 65...' I dont think it means 'heavy print'. I think it means heavy *readers* of print, as a medium.

It is talking about the tendency of older readers to read physical printed matter like newspapers, in preference to reading online.

With 'September Vogue' I think heavy print means 'densely typed information' or 'pages teeming with text'.

With 'the use of different media' I think it means that the internet is a heavy *proponent of* print - meaning - it contains a lot of textual information.

'Print' can mean 'physically printed' but it can also mean 'textual information' - even when seen on a screen or phone. So I think there's some blurring of meaning there.

So I think these examples are actually different - the phrase 'heavy print' means something different in each.

'Heavy print' can also mean an emboldened typeface.